# Can I upgrade to 18.10 from 18.04 with the same python packages installed?

Tags: 18.04, 18.10

Are all the python packages installed in 18.04 support on 18.10 ? because all my development packages are installed in 18.04.

Comment: Read the Ubuntu 18.10 Release Notes https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CosmicCuttlefish/ReleaseNotes

Comment: @waltinator Reading the release notes only will tell him what python versions are available in the newer Ubuntu version, but not if his packages might get uninstalled etc. if he upgrades.

Comment: So to make us able to answer this you might want to list all packages you have installed. While I'm pretty sure they will exist on 18.10 as they did on 18.04 without knowing which packages you have installed on your DEV stack no one really can answer if they will survive an upgrade.